# Maximum sum of sublist with a specific length

Tags: python, list, max, sublist

I'm supposed to write a function which takes two numbers, the first is a given number, and the second is the length for the maximum sublist that I'm supposed to find:
for example input (1234,2)
the output would be 7

this is my code so far, it just computes the sum of the entire digits:

```
def altsum_digits(n,d):
b=str(n)
c=[]
for digit in b:
    c.append(int(digit))

maxthere=0
realmax=0
for a in str(d):             
    for i in c:
        maxthere=max(0,(maxthere+int(i)))
        realmax=max(maxthere,realmax)
        maxthere==0
print(realmax)
```

Comment: So... what's going wrong? Do you get an error? If so what? Do you have a question?

Comment: Just a suggestion for creating your list ```c```, you can do it all in one go with ```c = [int(l) for l in str(n)]``` which is much cleaner and gets rid of the intermediate variable ```b```

Comment: Your example is not that clear.

Comment: is it any combination or just adjacent digits?  i.e. is `(5005,2)` 5 or 10?

Comment: Running your code with (1234,2) as inputs gives a final ```realmax``` value of 4, not 7

Comment: my code just gives the sum of all numbers in the list, for example (5005,2) is supposed to give 5.

Comment: I need to find the maximum sum of digits, (number of digits is given in the second input)

Comment: @user3369309, I think you're confusing the sum and max values.  Right now your script finds the maximum single digit in ```n```.  Do you want it to find the sum of all the single digits?  And how is ```d``` supposed to be used?

Comment: d the the length of the sublists that I want to check, I need the maximum of them, for example (1234,2) I would check 3 then 5 then 7 and 7 would be the answer

Comment: @user3369309 See my answer. I believe I definitely answered according to what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's clarify to make sure we're on the same page.

Inputs: 1) a list `li` of digits; 2) `n`

Output: the slice from `li` of length `n` that has maximal sum.

```
li = [4,2,1,7,1,3,8,4,7,8,1]

n = 2

slices = (li[x:x+n] for x in range(len(li)-n+1))

max(map(sum,slices))
Out[113]: 15
```

Comment: @user3369309 uh... no?  It works exactly like hugh bothwell's code, and both give expected outputs for the inputs we've shown.

Answer (score 1):

By what i get from question, this should do what you want:

```
def do(n, d):
    print sum(sorted([int(x) for x in str(n)])[-d:])
```

Answer (score 1):

let's say you get a number n, and a length k.

What you have to do is first turn n into a list of numbers, and then use a sliding window of size k where at each step you add the next number, and substract the first one in the sliding window, and keep track of the max_sum so you can return it at the end.

The function would look something like this

```
def altsum_digits(n, k):
    list_n = [int(x) for x in str(n)]
    max_sum = sum(list_n[:k])

    for i in range(k, len(list_n)):
        current_sum = current_sum + list_n[i] - list_n[i - k]
        max_sum = max(current_sum, max_sum)

    return max_sum
```

It's an O(n) solution, so it's a lot better than generating all sublists of size k. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
def sublists(lst, n):
    return (lst[i:i+n] for i in range(len(lst) - n + 1))

def max_sublist_sum(lst, n):
    return max(sum(sub) for sub in sublists(lst, n))

max_sublist_sum([1,2,3,4], 2)   # => 7
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
def altsum_digits(n, d):
    l = list(map(int, str(n)))
    m = c = sum(l[:d])
    for i in range(0, len(l)-d):
        c = c - l[i] + l[i+d]
        if c > m: m = c
    print m

altsum_digits(1234,2)
>>> 7
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're asking, and here is my solution. I've tested it on your input as well as other inputs with varying lengths of substring. This code finds the **maximum sum of adjacent substrings in the input**.

```
def sum_of_sublist(input, maxLength):
    input_array = [int(l) for l in str(input)]
    tempMax = 0
    realMax = 0
    for i in range(len(input_array) - (maxLength - 1)):
        for inc in range(0, maxLength):
            tempMax += input_array[i+inc]
        if tempMax > realMax:
            realMax = tempMax
        tempMax = 0
    print realMax


sum_of_sublist(1234, 2)
```

So, for an input for the call `sum_of_sublist(1234, 2)`, it will print the value 7 because the largest sum of 2 consecutive numbers is 3 + 4 = 7. Similarly, for the call`sum_of_sublist(12531, 3)`, the program will print 10 because the largest sum of 3 consecutive numbers is 2 + 5 + 3 = 10.